# How do you cast I list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, base-class

I am trying to cast a list.

```
public class Base
{
}

public class Item: Base
{
}
```

Then in another class i have the property requestList1

```
public List<Base> requestList1{ get; set; }
```

Attempts:

```
requestList1 = form.item.Cast<Item>()
requestList1  = new List<Item>(form.item)
```

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: `requestList1 = form.item.OfType<Item>().ToList();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter form.item is a calls called form with a property item: public IList<Item> item{ get; set; }

Comment: `requestList1 = form.item.Cast<Base>().ToList();` since initial `form.item` is of type `List<Item>` target is of type `List<Base>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly cast them to each other. Consider the case:

```
public class Base
{
}

public class Item: Base
{
}

public class EvilItem: Base
{
}
```

So let's try to cast from `List<Item>` to `List<Base>`:

```
List<Item> a = new List<Item>();
List<Base> b = (List<Base>)a;

b.Add(new EvilItem());
```

Aaand we have a problem. Since `List<T>` is a reference-type, both `a` and `b` are now references to the same list. And we just added an `EvilItem` to a `List<Item>` - something which should NOT be allowed. But the line `b.Add(new EvilItem());` is completely legit, because `b` is a `List<Base>`.

This goes the other way too. If you create a `List<Base>` then you can't cast it to a `List<Item>`, because some items in there could be `EvilItem`. Or maybe they will get added later.

So .NET forbids such casting.

You have a few options. First, you can create a copy of the list:

```
b = new List<Base>(a);
```

Now `a` and `b` are two completely different lists that just happen to have the same contents. Keep in mind that changing one list will NOT change the other.

Alternatively, if you don't need to modify the list, you can use it as an enumerable instead:

```
IEnumerable<Base> c = a;
```

Why this works is a bit of a longer story, but to simplify it - `IEnumerable` only allows you to read the list, so you can't do bad things like add `EvilItem` to it. Thus it's allowed.

As for why `requestList1 = form.item.Cast<Item>()` didn't work - the `Cast<T>()` produces an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`, so you can't assign it. You could change it to `requestList1 = form.item.Cast<Base>().ToList()` and that would work - but it would also copy the list. That's another way to do it, actually, although it's a bit longer to write and I also suspect it's a little less efficient (but I don't have proof for that)

Comment: You haven't explained why `requestList1 = form.item.Cast<Item>()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Umm... do I have to?

Comment: Well, the OP included it in their question. It seems like it might be relevant.

Comment: @Enigmativity - OK, added it.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I don't know what's up with that. You've done a pretty good answer. Upvoting now.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks. :) I'm not much concerned with rep, but I would like to know why people consider this a bad answer.

Comment: I wish I knew. Apart from my request - which was fairly minor - I thought it was a good answer. I was just suggesting to fix up the one small hole.